# What do I need to import to do bitwise operations?

Tags: haskell, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to use bitwise operators and I can't figure out what I need to import.

```
$ cat tmp.hs
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

mask = 0xff :: Word64
v = 98213 :: Word64

lsb = mask & v
```

And this is what I see:

```
$ ghci tmp.hs 
GHCi, version 9.2.8: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp.hs, interpreted )

tmp.hs:7:12: error:
    Variable not in scope: (&) :: Word64 -> Word64 -> t
  |
7 | lsb = mask & v
  |            ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
ghci>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already imported this. But in Haskell, the bitwise operators are [**`(.&.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-38-.), [**`(.|.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-124-.), and [**`(.^.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-94-.), so:

```
lsb = mask .&. v
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use [.&.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-38-.) from `Data.Bits`. The `&` operand is the reverse of `$` in Haskell [from base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-)